# Unit testing if file exists in local file system via Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I am able to test the below code successfully in EMR cluster via spark. But I am not able to write unit test case with local file system in intelliJ. Could anyone please help me with how to specify local file system in intelliJ in below code.

Working in EMR cluster

```
FileSystem.get(new URI("s3n://bucket"), sc.hadoopConfiguration).exists(new Path("/path_to_check"))
```

Doesn't work in intelliJ. It always returns false

```
FileSystem.get(new URI("file://somelocal/bucket"), sc.hadoopConfiguration).exists(new Path("/some/local/path_to_check"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`

```
def isFileExists(path: String, pattern: String)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Boolean = {
    val fixedPath = path.stripSuffix("/") + "/"
    val conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(path), conf)
    val reg = new Regex(pattern)

    try {
      val files = fs.listFiles(new Path(fixedPath), true)
      var flag = false
      // hack because listFiles returns RemoteIterator which not an inheritor of java.util.Iterator
      while (files.hasNext) {
        reg.findFirstMatchIn(files.next().toString) match {
          case Some(_) => flag = true
          case None =>
        }
      }
      flag
    } catch {
      // if dir doesn't exist
      case _: java.io.FileNotFoundException => false
      case e: Throwable => throw e
    } finally {
      fs.close()
    }
  }
```

it works with s3, hdfs and local file system and you can write unit tests